# Can you Mass Disable the Marketing User field (UserPermissionMarketingUser) for multiple User records using Data Loader?

Tags: reporting, data-loader, user-record

I am attempting to mass disable the User record's Marketing User field (UserPermissionMarketingUser) for certain user records that exist within a test SF org. The steps I used were:

1. Create a report  for all 797 users who have profiles that do not match these three profiles:

   a) System Administrator

   b) Marketing User

   c) Marketing
2. The report headers contains these fields :

   a) Profile

   b) User Id

   c) Username

   d) Marketing User
3. Export the report into a CSV file.
4. Change the contents of all the Marketing User values from '1' to '0' in order to disable the field.
5. Using Data Loader with the Update setting for the User object, Upload the updated CSV file back into Salesforce.

However Data Loader does not recognize this field. It does not exist when I try to map the SF fields with the columns in the CSV file. It is the only SF field it does not seem to recognize during mapping.

Q) How can I mass update this field without using Apex?
Thanks

Comment: plural `UserPermissionsMarketingUser`

Comment: Sorry @cropredy I meant to spell that field correctly but it still doesn;t exist. I checked the Schema Builder  on User as well as the Object Manager for User object's Field and Relationship section and could not find UserPermissionsMarketingUser field however it exists on the User Record  which perplexed me. How can a standard field be hidden on both Schema builder and that object's Object Manager too?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The User field you want to change is `UserPermissionsMarketingUser`. You can load into this field using Data Loader.

Comment: Sorry @DavidSchach but there was no field that appeared on the Data Loader for me to load data into. I searched the Map fields and did see it. It didn't show up in Dataloader for me. It could be that me Data loader credentials are based on a user that may not be Sys Admin capable.My client 's SF Admin group have possibly set this field to Hidden from the Marketing User profile that I am using for login credentials (?). I think that may be it. I will test this out.

Comment: when I compare the User object's fields in the Object Manager's Fields and Relationship for the User Object , UserPermissionsMarketingUser does not exist yet on the Detail Record it does. How is this set up?

Comment: After looking at a couple links that seem to hint at using Bulk API feature on Data Loader to run this.

Comment: I see the field when I use SoqlXplorer to describe it. And when using Excel Connector I see it as well. It isn't in that field list on the User object manager page, but it's there. The field is in Data Loader, I promise, at least since API 18.0.

Comment: OK Thanks @DavidSchach  I will need to check on my Data Loader Version.

Comment: I have Data Loader  Version 45.0.0 and I don't see that API field listed anywhere in the mapping. –

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank @DavidSchach for pointing me in the right direction regarding tools other than Data Loader to access the Marketing User field since I already use the latest version (45.00) of this tool and I still was unable to map the Marketing User field from Salesforce User detail Record with my CSV File's Marketing User column. That issue occurred because the Salesforce Marketing User field that was being retrieved by Data Loader was hidden from this tool.

**Solution:**
My Solution was to go to **Workbench** because this tool allowed me to do an update on User object and its mapping did give me access to the Marketing User field (UserPermissionsMarketingUser). Here is the abbreviated screen shot and the results.
[image]
[image]

Comment: You're very welcome. I hate to ask for it, but would you mind marking my answer as correct? Thanks!